# Error when I'm using segue to move from one viewController to another in swift 2

Tags: ios, segue, swift2

I'm using segue to move from one view controller to another and I connected the first and second view from layout also but when moving from first to the second view the following error appear and the app return again to the registration screen( the first screen before Enter PIN ) , I know all concepts about using segue to move from view Controller to another also i used it before and it's working correctly but I don't know what is the problem in this case!

First View Controller name : EnterPINVC

Second View Controller name : chooserViewController

segue identifier name : enter_main

Code : This line for moving from first to second activity after some of process

```
                    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil )

                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("enter_main", sender: self)
```

Error:

```
present <ÿ™ŸàÿßÿµŸÑ_.chooserViewController: 0x12d884d00> on <ÿ™ŸàÿßÿµŸÑ_.EnterPINVC: 0x12d8b2d80> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Comment: You are dismissing a viewController, and then telling the same viewController to present another viewController. I think something there is going wrong.

Comment: I removed this line and it's working now but why if the user used NSUserDefaults at one view controller and want to check the value of this NSUserDefaults at another one where we want to check this value ( is initial view controller ) it's return null so make exception in the checking process

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by removed this line

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil )
```